# unity firebase catch exception errors

Tags: exception, unity-game-engine, firebase, try-catch, storage

Good Day!

We are using unity on working with firebase. We referred to firebase guides for unity. We tried to download files from storage which does not exist and returned an error that retry limit is exceeded. We would like to catch this error  and show our customized error message since the default exception for retry limit exceed is very long. Here is an example of our code for printing the exception.

```
imaginary_ref.GetBytesAsync (maxAllowedSize).ContinueWith (task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled) {
            Debug.Log  (task.Exception.ToString());
        } 
        else if (task.IsCompleted) {
            Debug.Log ("Successful download!");
        } else{
            Debug.Log  (task.Exception.ToString());
        }
    });
```

In the example above, we would like to capture the task exception and print our own error but there is no documentation for that.

Ex.

```
if (ErrorRetryLimitExceeded) 
Debug.Log("Retry Limit Exceeded");
else if (ErrorCanceled )
Debug.Log("Download was canceled by user");
```

Also does firebase now have exception reference for Firebase Authorization for Unity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase developer here.

Yes, this should be possible with Firebase Storage using StorageException.ErrorCode.

```
imaginary_ref.GetBytesAsync (maxAllowedSize).ContinueWith (task => {
    if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled) {
        AggregateException ex = task.Exception as AggregateException;
        if (ex != null) {
           StorageException inner = ex.InnerExceptions[0] as StorageException;
           if (inner != null && inner.ErrorCode == StorageException.ErrorRetryLimitExceeded) {
             Debug.Log ("retry failed!");
           }
        }
    } 
    else if (task.IsCompleted) {
        Debug.Log ("Successful download!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot. I noticed I can't do that for FirebaseAuth?

Comment: Is there something similar for FirebaseAuth? This would be very useful

Comment: Answer for Firebase auth- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53036083/google-firebase-how-to-catch-specific-auth-exception-errors-unity/53036084#53036084

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me.

```
    public int HandleIsFaulted(Task t)
    {
        System.AggregateException ex = t.Exception as System.AggregateException;
        if (ex != null)
        {
            Firebase.FirebaseException fbEx = null;
            foreach (System.Exception e in ex.InnerExceptions)
            {
                fbEx = e as Firebase.FirebaseException;
                if (fbEx != null)
                { break; }
                if (e.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Firebase.FirebaseException innerEx = e.InnerException as Firebase.FirebaseException;
                    if (innerEx != null)
                    {
                        fbEx = innerEx;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (fbEx != null)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Encountered a FirebaseException:" + fbEx.ErrorCode);
                return fbEx.ErrorCode;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```