# Google Firebase how to catch specific Auth exception errors - Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, exception, firebase-authentication, try-catch

-How to catch Auth exception errors - Unity
-How to catch if user/email exists - Unity
-Where to find the list of Auth exceptions error code - Unity

*I found a lot of answers for Android so I decided to finally write my solution for Unity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is simple- either use the following function on the task you are trying to achieve -

```
protected bool LogTaskCompletion(Task task, string operation)
{
    bool complete = false;
    if (task.IsCanceled)
    {
        Debug.Log(operation + " canceled.");
    }
    else if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
        Debug.Log(operation + " encounted an error.");
        foreach (Exception exception in task.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
        {
            string authErrorCode = "";
            Firebase.FirebaseException firebaseEx = exception as Firebase.FirebaseException;
            if (firebaseEx != null)
            {
                authErrorCode = String.Format("AuthError.{0}: ",
                  ((Firebase.Auth.AuthError)firebaseEx.ErrorCode).ToString());
            }
            Debug.Log("number- "+ authErrorCode +"the exception is- "+ exception.ToString());
            string code = ((Firebase.Auth.AuthError)firebaseEx.ErrorCode).ToString();
            Debug.Log(code);
        }
    }
    else if (task.IsCompleted)
    {
        Debug.Log(operation + " completed");
        complete = true;
    }
    return complete;
}
```

The printed output `Debug.Log(code)` is the exception code you are looking for.  Now you can compare it -  `if (code.Equals("some specific exception...."))` and complete it with your code.

**Example**:

**How to catch if user/email exists** 
Let's say we sign up a new user with `CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync` and we want to catch the error " The email address is already in use" 
We can use my function to find out what the error code we need to compare and it will print to output "EmailAlreadyInUse". Next all I need to do is to check `if ((code).Equals("EmailAlreadyInUse"))` 
-Another possible way is to find the error code in a list-

**List of Auth exceptions error code FOR UNITY**
All the exceptions are under class `Firebase.Auth.AuthError` you can see them either on your code editor, or on Firebase website under - Unity - Firebase.Auth - Overview (under AuthError).

Hope it helps!

Comment: In my case, using  `fbEx = e.GetBaseException() as FirebaseException;` instead of  `Firebase.FirebaseException firebaseEx = exception as Firebase.FirebaseException;` works perfectly

Comment: Thank you so much! Answered my question and taught me something about exceptions too.